# JAVA - How to store and read an RSA private key from an sqlite db

Tags: java, database, sqlite, get, private-key

I store the keys as byte[] to the sqlite database.
When I want to get the private Key with:

```
ResultSet rs  = pstmt.executeQuery();
                    while(rs.next()){                       
                        KeyFactory rsaKeyFac =  KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
                        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(rs.getBytes(1));
                        RSAPrivateCrtKey privKey;
                        privKey = (RSAPrivateCrtKey) rsaKeyFac.generatePrivate(keySpec);
                        result = privKey;
                }
```

I only get :

```
sun.security.rsa.RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl@fffd1339
```

My public key retrievement works! But with the private key and the certificate I don't get it.
Can anyone help?

Comment: That code looks OK. The problem is with how you're using the result.

Comment: What do I have to do with the result to get my private key?

Comment: The result *is* a private key object. What do you need it for?

Comment: I need it to sign a String.

Comment: And? Does it work?